# Configuring git log to use mailmap by default

Tags: git, git-log

Is there a way to configure git log to use a mailmap file by default? Without having to specify a format (or an alias for one).

Comment: That question is quite unclear. Do you want to specify a default output format in which log respects a .mailmap, as specified by [the git-log man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) or do you mean to supply a defailt mailmap file?

Comment: Neither. I explicitly do not want to specify the format but I'm not concerned with where the mailmap file is either. I do want git log commands to use the mailmap file though, they don't by default.

Comment: Well, if you always want to use a mailmap file, you'll have to specify a default, or git wont know what to do. the git-log man refers to the git-shortlog and [git-config man about "mailmap.file"](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)

Comment: This isn't really relevant to the question, but the default is to use one in the root of the repository.

Comment: It is very relevant, because that's what youre asking. You should have mentioned that in the question right away. The links I posted explains how git log uses .mailmap and how you can set a default with git config. If you need more help, I'll draw up a proper answer when I can. Meanwhile, you should remove the "logging" tag since this question has nothing to do with logging.

Comment: No, it's fundamentally, absolutely, categorically not what I'm asking. Perhaps English isn't your first language but as the documentation implies, git log does not use a .mailmap in the default location at the root of the repository by default. git shortlog does, git log does not. I couldn't care less if I had to explicitly define the location of the mailmap file anyway - I just want git log to use it without specifying a custom format. This is _nothing_ to do with where the .mailmap actually resides or the configuration to find it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have Git 2.4.1. If you set `log.mailmap` config to true, that will set it to work with `git log` also

```
git config --global log.mailmap true
```

Comment: In case it helps future visitors who are using a [`pretty-formats`](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) log, the setting above is ignored. Instead, [look up](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) the `.mailmap`-respecting placeholders (`%aN`, `%aE` for author and `%cN`, `%cE` for committer).

Answer (score 16):

You can set up defaults in your `.gitconfig` file. The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) says:

> **log.mailmap**
>
> If true, makes `git-log`, `git-show`, and
>   `git-whatchanged` assume `--use-mailmap`.

This will look for a `.mailmap` only in the root of the working tree.

To set:

```
git config --global log.mailmap true
```

**Global `mailmap` file**

> **mailmap.file**
>
> The location of an augmenting mailmap file. The default
>   mailmap, located in the root of the repository, is loaded first, then
>   the mailmap file pointed to by this variable. The location of the
>   mailmap file may be in a repository subdirectory, or somewhere outside
>   of the repository itself. See `git-shortlog` and `git-blame`.

To set:

```
git config --global mailmap.file ~/.mailmap
```

**Advanced**

You can also use a repository blob as a mailmap file, see `mailmap.blob` in the documentation linked to above.

Answer (score 6):

As of [git 1.8.2](https://git-htmldocs.googlecode.com/git/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt), `git log` takes a `--use-mailmap` parameter to enable this behavior.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that this isn't a feature, yet, due to [hysterical raisins](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-log-to-use-mailmap-by-default-td7570862.html).

Comment: aboriginal lynx died, but the archive has a copy: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-log-to-use-mailmap-by-default-td7570862.html

Answer (score 4):

Warning Git 2.23 (Q3 2019) states that a future version of Git would use log.mailmap *by default*

The "`git log`" command learns to issue a warning when `log.mailmap` configuration is not set and `--[no-]mailmap` option is not used, to prepare users for future versions of Git that uses the mailmap by default.

See [commit ef60740](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef60740e9efb364d8bb0fba120adecf860cc8ed0), [commit 2d9c569](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2d9c56905804baa76069e2176035aebd62ddff15), [commit f0596ec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0596ecc8de9bdbdfc394b2f153ff67f64fc4615) (15 Jul 2019) by [Ariadne Conill (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c7cf2de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7cf2de8fcec29e1f834ca75a8468f91a0a37637), 25 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `log`: add warning for unspecified `log.mailmap` setting
>
> Based on **[discussions around changing the log.mailmap default to being enabled](https://public-inbox.org/git/20190621221650.hoet5juwjhjcw5mh@hashpling.org/)**, it was decided that a transitional period is required.
>
> Accordingly, we announce this transitional period with a warning message.

The warning message is:

> `log.mailmap` is not set; **its implicit value will change in an upcoming release**.
>
> - To squelch this message and preserve current behaviour, set the `log.mailmap` configuration value to `false`.
> - To squelch this message and adopt the new behaviour now, set the `log.mailmap` configuration value to `true`.

[Initial description](https://public-inbox.org/git/20181213120940.26477-1-cb@hashpling.org/):

> People who have changed their name or email address will usually know that they need to set '`log.mailmap`' in order to have their new details reflected for old commits with '`git log`', but others who interact with them may not know or care enough to enable this option.
>
> Change the default for '`git log`' and friends to always use mailmap so
>   that everyone gets to see canonical names and email addresses.

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), "`git log`" learns "`--[no-]mailmap`" as a synonym to "`--[no-]use-mailmap`"

See [commit 88acccd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88acccda38602bd420274cee6501efb3204a8fa9), [commit c28b036](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c28b036fe3701b8aac214e94994ee806ba49ec9a), [commit 7c28058](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c280589cffa6f55f6bef0496776334f1e3cdcb5) (16 Mar 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9404128](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9404128b34bc1abfc99b20f2ce4ca14a2828d7a0), 28 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`log`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88acccda38602bd420274cee6501efb3204a8fa9): give `--[no-]use-mailmap` a more sensible synonym `--[no-]mailmap`
>
> The option name "`--use-mailmap`" looks OK, but it becomes awkward when you have to negate it, i.e. "`--no-use-mailmap`".
>
> I, perhaps with many other users, always try "`--no-mailmap`" and become unhappy to see it fail.
>
> Add an alias "`--[no-]mailmap`" to remedy this.