# Git log --pretty: Only include author first name (not family name)

Tags: git, format

I recently discovered `git log --oneline` and it's great, but I'd like to see the author in there as well. To do this I've come up with the following which does exactly that:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%C(auto)%h%x09%an %x09%s"
```

Now, some of my coworkers have pretty long last names, but they all have different first names. **How would I include only the first name and leave out the family name of the commit author?** Is it even possible?

Comment: Your command dosen't work. Further, the name is specified via git config, where first and last name are stored together in the same string. So the only way to do this would be to pass the output of `git log` to `tr` or some other bash utility

Comment: Ah, I forgot to unescape the quotes. I've updated the command and tested that it works.

Hmm, well, using another bash utility feels like cheeting. Maybe one can ellipse the name after a certain number of characters?

Comment: Well, you can ellipse the name using something like `git log --pretty=format:"%C(auto)%h%x09%<(8,trunc)%an %s"` but it's not exactly pretty..

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777171/configuring-git-log-to-use-mailmap-by-default

Comment: Didn't know about mailmap! That seems like the most elegant option so far. I'll post the resulting command as an answer for others who stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [Andrew C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4021077/andrew-c) noted in a comment, one can use mailmap for this purpose:

First create a .mailmap-file in the repo root, listing all the contributors like so:

```
John <john.doe@example.com> John Doe <john.doe@example.com>
```

Then simply use the following git log format which respects the .mailmap:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%C(auto)%h %<(8)%aN %s"
```

(Notice the %aN instead of the %an)